# PostgreSQL query - show which rows are locked

Tags: postgresql, locking

I would like to query data from a table, and if a row is locked, show it as a different color.  Is this possible using postgresql's locking for update?

e.g.
select
*,
(select  from pg_x -- link row somehow )
from table

thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is no good way to do that. The row locks are stored in the row (system column [`xmax`](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/whats-in-an-xmax/)), but this attribute serves other purposes too, and the flags that determine if it is indeed a row lock or perhaps a rolled back update are not exposed via SQL.

There are only unpleasant alternatives:

1. Use the [`pageinspect`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pageinspect.html) contrib module to examine those flags. That would be a second scan of the table, and such a query doesn't respect MVCC visibility.
2. Run a second query:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM atable
   FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED;
   ```

   That would lock all rows in the table and be very bad for concurrency.

Besides, that information would be pretty useless for the user. In a well-written application, row locks are only held for split seconds, so the information would be outdated by the time it reaches the user.

Comment: Thank you.  I have a multi-user application in which I lock a row FOR UPDATE so that it will avoid multiple users working on the same row. Looks like I'll end up building it on my own. there's an added benefit that I can show who it is locked by.

Comment: You should on no account have a use interaction inside a database transaction. Database transactions must be short. Add a boolean or timestamp column to the table that indicates locking by the application.